# CSS transition issue on Chrome with Flexslider

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexslider

I'm using [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) to display a list of elements which are quite complex.

Basically each item has:

- a background image in `position: absolute`
- a foreground containing text and images

I have the following issue (only in Chrome): the foreground goes to the back during sliding transition and then comes back to front when the transition is finished.

Do you have any idea of investigation paths for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/179 I solved the issue by using the following option at slider creation:

```
useCSS: false
```